Can you spend Luck on CON rolls made to avoid death?
In a recent Call of Cthulhu 7e game, my investigator was stabbed by a villainous priest for nine points of damage and was knocked Unconscious with the Dying and Major Wound conditions. This marked the first time we'd ever had a Dying character in the game, and we had never used the Dying rules up to this point.
Per Call of Cthulhu 7e rules in my copy of the investigator's handbook, Dying works like this:

When treating a dying character, successful First Aid stabilizes him
or her for one hour and grants 1 temporary hit point. At the end of
the hour, and each hour thereafter, the character must make a
successful CON roll to remain stabilized, otherwise (with a failed CON
roll) the character is dying and loses the temporary hit point, and
must now make a CON roll per round thereafter to stave off death.

It came up in a Discord chat after the game whether or not I could use Luck on the CON roll, should it get bad enough to reach that point. I had a lot of Luck points saved up from not using them much throughout the game, so at the time this could have played a huge role in saving my character if it was allowed.
My Keeper's interpretation was that given the following text explaining the Luck rules:

After the player has made a skill roll (using a skill or
characteristic), Luck points may be spent to alter the result. The
player can use Luck points to alter a roll on a 1-for-1 basis... Luck points may
not be spent on Luck rolls, damage rolls, Sanity rolls, or rolls to
determine the amount of Sanity points lost. A player may spend any
amount of Luck points (up to their current Luck value) on a roll. A
player may only spend Luck to alter one of their own dice rolls.

The Keeper's view at the time was that since CON is a characteristic roll, she interpreted this to mean that we could indeed spend Luck points on a CON roll to stay alive if it came to that, given that it is not included in the list of exceptions where you may not use Luck.
It thankfully didn't end up being necessary as another character was able to save me with a First Aid roll, but I am curious whether anyone can give me an official answer as I wasn't able to find a clear consensus after looking through forum posts and Reddit discussions on the topic of death CON rolls.

Your keeper made the right call
Skill rolls are explained on page 82 of the core rulebook, and the explanation says:

The term "skill roll" is used regardless of whether a skill or a characteristic is used.

So there is no contradiction in the text "After the player has made a skill roll (using a skill or characteristic), ", the parentheses are just a reminder that a skill roll can involve a skill, or just a plain characteristic, it does not imply that you are trying to use a skill.
As CON is a characteristic, a CON roll to stabilize is a skill roll, and you can apply Luck to it.

Thank you for the confirmation and the clarification on skill rolls! Knowing that characteristic rolls count as skill rolls when it comes to rulings answers a lot of other questions I had.
